# Responsive NavBar like StackOverflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive navigation bar, similar to the one on Stack Overflow. I have attached an image of the layout I'm trying to achieve.[image: Layout]

For simplicity, I added some values to make it easier to follow. There is the outer div that encapsulates the whole page, `outer-wrapper` and the main div that encapsulates the main content (navigation bar, main content, and footer), `main-wrapper`.

Now suppose that `outer-wrapper` is 1000px wide and `main-wrapper` is 800px wide, then there is 100px of buffer on the left and right side. When the window shrinks, I want the buffer to be used up before any of the main content changes.

**CSS**

```
    .outer-wrapper {
        width:  100%;
    }

    .main-wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav-home {
        position: fixed;
        top: -30px;
        left: -30px;
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class='outer-wrapper'>
      <div class='main-wrapper'>
        <div class='nav-bar'>...</div>
        <div class='main-content'>...</div>
        <div class='footer'>...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when the window shrinks to match the width of `main-wrapper` at 800px, there is still a left and right margin in the navigation bar. How would I ensure the width of the navigation bar matches the width of the main content and footer when the left and right margin is shrunk to 0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stripped out some of your styles from the `.nav-bar` class and it seems to be performing as you require - am I missing something?

I've added colours to help visualise the resizing.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    width:  100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-bar {
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.main-content {
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-wrapper'>
  <div class='main-wrapper'>
    <div class='nav-bar'>Nav Bar</div>
    <div class='main-content'>Main Content</div>
    <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh oops, I realized there were some extra margin-left's/right's that I had somewhere within the navigation bar items. Thanks for your help though! Hopefully this will help others looking to do the same thing :P

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outer-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .main-wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .main-wrapper > * {
        padding: 10px;
        flex: 1 100%;
      }

      .nav-bar {
        background: tomato;
      }

      .footer {
        background: lightgreen;
      }

      .main-content {
        background: deepskyblue;
      }

      .aside-1 {
        background: gold;
      }

      .aside-2 {
        background: hotpink;
      }

      @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
        .aside {
          flex: 1 0 0;
        }
      }

      @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
        .main-content {
          flex: 3 0px;
        }
        .aside-1 {
          order: 1;
        }
        .main-content {
          order: 2;
        }
        .aside-2 {
          order: 3;
        }
        .footer {
          order: 4;
        }
      }

      body {
        padding: 2em;
      }
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <nav class="nav-bar">Navbar</nav>
        <main class="main-content">content</main>
        <aside class="aside aside-1">aside 1</aside>
        <aside class="aside aside-2">aside 2</aside>
        <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
```

this is the code that I made, hopefully it will help you and what you expect